# Get the clicked list item with a click event on the ul tag (parent)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this:

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#credits">Credits</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

and I want to get the clicked item list href value with an event listener on the ul tag, something like this:

```
    $('.tabs').click(function () {
        let getClickedItem = 
    })
```

Comment: Can you specify what exactly what you want to see? Is it link value, or text, or HTML itself?

Comment: I want to get the link value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code and out console, this should be thing you are looking for:

```
$(function(){
            $(".tabs li a").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log($(this).attr('href'));
            })
        })
```

Comment: Why do I have to put preventDefault()?
It seems working without.

Comment: Ok, sorry I haven't seen the end of your response, and in which case the event does not get explicitly handled?

Comment: @Hunam you need to put preventDefault() to stop going to the links you have in the "href" attribute. for example you can put any website to check instead of #home or #credits, it will automatically it will go there untill you put back preventDefault()

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `target` property on the event object:

```js
$('.tabs').click((event) => {
  console.log(event.target);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#credits">Credits</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

This will however give the element that was clicked which in this case would most definitelly be the anchor tags.

You say you want the *list item* that is clicked. You could just attach the event listener directly to those:

```js
$('.tabs li').click(function () {
  console.log('click', this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#credits">Credits</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```